# prevent simultaneous logins from the same user in javafx

Tags: java, authentication, javafx

I'm building a javaFX based server-client application.
the app has a mysql database that holds users info including password for login purposes, but what i want is to prevent simultaneous login from the user, i have done in before using HttpServletRequest and Session but that was for a WEB application, is there a way to do the same thing for a desktop application?

Comment: Probably the most common way is to store a sessionID and last access timeStamp. You can generate them in the same manner as webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be somewhat tricky. The client should present a unique random ID per connection and the server should store it.

The tricky part is knowing when the user logs out. In a normal situation, you can create a REST method for logging out, but what happens in case of ungraceful shutdown? How does the server know that the client is no longer there?

I see couple ways to work this around:

1. Keep the user signed in with the initial session. Once the user has signed in, reject the new authentication requests. That's difficult because you need to find a way to handle an ungraceful shutdown of the client storing a timestamp of the last message exchanged by that session.
2. Destroy the old session if you receive a new one. This way you avoid situation of solution 1 and the user will always be able to sign in. Old sessions will be invalidated.